# asp.net: How to get a button to affect the page contents

Tags: asp.net

In Page_Load I populate an asp:Table with a grid of images. I have a button that when pressed I would like it to repopulate the page with different images.

However it appears that when the button is pressed Page_Load is called again, followed by the script specified by the button. I thought that I could simply set a variable in the button script which is checked during Page_Load, but this will not work.

What is the most asp.netish way to approach this? Should I be populating my table somewhere other than in Page_Load, or should my button be doing something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button event gets called after page load.  As such, you should put your button code in there.

I'm not terribly sure why you'd try to stuff all of your event code into Page_Load, but it's best to keep it separated.

**GOOD**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MethodThatDynamicallyCreatesControls();
}

protected void MyImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyImage.Property = newValue;
  MyImage2.Property = newValue2;
  PopulateTables(newValues);
}
```

**BAD**

```
protected void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    //Check to see if "MyButton" is in the Request 
    // if it is, it's the button that was clicked
    if (Request["MyButton"])
    {
      MyImage.Property = newValue;
      MyImage2.Property = newValue;
      PopulateTables(newValues);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to put everything into Page_Load, but I did want Page_Load to either react to the button press (which it can't if it is called first), or to leave the populating to the button routine, which IsPostBack allows me to do. Thanks

Comment: According to http://forums.asp.net/t/1129248.aspx OnClick events dynamically added to ImageButtons will only fire if they are added during Page_Load

Comment: Yes, you have to re-build your control structure every page request.  That doesn't mean that your Page_Load should also do all of your logic.  I'll update to clarify

Answer (score 3):

As rick said, it's all a matter of understanding the postback.

page_load gets fired every time the page is refreshed. however in many cases, you only want certain things to happen on the first time a page is loaded. in your case, you want the default images to load. by putting all 'one time' events for a page load in a

```
if (!Page.IsPostback )
{
}
```

it will only fire on the first time the page is loaded. this is what you want to load your first set of images.

Then in your button click event (which triggers a postback), the code within the if statement will not execute again. and you can load your second set of images in your button's event handler.

Answer (score 2):

That button you're using should call a method in your code behind,so you can know that the button is was clicked, ex:

```
protected void Important_ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do what I want to do
}

<asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="MakeChanges"
       OnClick="Important_ButtonClicked" 
       runat="server"/>
```

Actually I understand what your problem is now, seems like you just have values being set in your page load with **no condition check** *in you page load*, so every time you have a postback it refreshes the page to original state, the reason for that is because everytime you trigger a refresh(postback) on the page, the pageload method is invoked, so you need to set original setting in your page load,but have them in the condition, as 
`if(!Page.Postback)` which gets triggered the first time you visit this page. Which means this is where your defaults go and `if(Page.Postback)` is where your always true things should go. ex:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
   // this is where I want things to always happen whenever the page is loaded
   //for example, no matter what happens I want a certain image in the background
   if(!Page.Postback)
   {
     //set my values for the first and only time
   }
   else //hint Page.Postback
   {  
       //you can play with the page here to make necessary changes
       //but Button click method will still be invoke so thats where button click 
       //changes should be made
   }
}
```

Comment: All the values I set in Page_Load seem to be cleared on each page refresh, so it looks like I have to set them each and every time.

Answer (score 1):

A PostBack happend when the page is reload. The first page load, Page.IsPostBack has value false. When an event happend, Page.IsPostBack has value true. 
So doing the thing like this will definitely works

```
void Page_Load()
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//do your first time binding data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Create Event Handlers in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx)

EDIT:
Your state change events are not going to fire correctly if you re-bind controls(ie:DropDownList) data on every postback.

```
void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //load your data
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if he has EnableViewState turned off (which, imo, you should for larger data controls) he will need to rebind on every postback so that his events will fire.

Comment: Without ViewState, events that detect changes in controls like dropdownlist.selectedindexchanged will not work.  I am also a fan of not using it when its not needed.  ASP.NET WebForms is built on ViewState.  If you don't use it or like it, you should be using MVC.

Comment: @rick: Right now I have a page that uses dynamically created radio buttons, doesn't have view state on, and it fires events just fine.  Rebinding during page_load is perfectly acceptable for dynamic controls with no viewstate.

Comment: @JustLoren Out of scope here for the question, but dynamic controls have to be re-added to the control tree to fire state change events, not re-bound.  There is a difference.  If you re-add it and re-bind it(ie. DropDownList) to data your state change event will have issues.

Comment: @rick: "In ASP.NET these values are automatically written back to the control’s properties immediately before Page_Load in a phase called “ProcessPostData”. ...dynamic controls are often created in Page_Load. Therefore in ProcessPostData the values cannot be restored. To work around this problem ASP.NET keeps track of which values could not be processed and starts a “ProcessPostData Second Try” **directly after Page_Load**."  This means that you can re-add *and* re-bind a dynamic DropDownList, and it'll function correctly. http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5550

Comment: @JustLoren: Interesting,  I will test some dynamic control state change events with ViewState off.  I think we are debating different points.  Thanks for the link though.